# Getting an approximate previous year's value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has the following sample rows:

```
Product Date        Revenue
A       2021-05-10  20
A       2021-03-20  10
A       2020-01-10  5
A       2020-03-10  6
A       2020-04-10  7
```

For each product and date, I'd like to get the closest date to last year from its original date. For example, the first row's date is 2021-05-10 the closest to the previous year for this date is 2020-04-10. The resulting output I'd like is the following:

```
Product Date        Revenue   PrevDate  PrevRevenue
A       2021-05-10  20        2020-04-10   7
A       2021-03-20  10        2020-03-10   6
A       2020-01-10  5         null         null
A       2020-03-10  6         null         null
A       2020-04-10  7         null         null
```

How would I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a lateral join:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t t1 left join lateral
     (select t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.product = t1.product and
            t2.date < dateadd(month, -6, t1.date)
      order by abs(t2.date - (t1.date - interval '1 year'))
     ) t2
     on 1=1;
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `mismatched input 'outer' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 39)`

Comment: @razer . . . You changed the database on the question.  I updated the answer.

Comment: I'm getting this error now: mismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>(line 2, pos 0)

Comment: The last parenthesis doesn't have a connecting parenthesis also

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different query than the one suggest by Gordon:

You could use the `LEFT LATERAL JOIN` to filter the closest date from a previous year from the current date, by subtracting a 1 year `interval` and ordering by it with a `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.prevdate,t2.prevrevenue FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL 
  (SELECT product,date,revenue FROM t t2
   WHERE t2.date < t1.date-interval'1 year' AND t1.product = t2.product
   ORDER BY abs(date_part('day',(t1.date-interval' 1year')-t2.date))   
   LIMIT 1) t2 (product,prevdate,prevrevenue) USING (product);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=df04f64b82e2f046cfad92ab886bf713)